# Resize photo with every extensions

Tags: php, upload, photo, image-resizing

i got the resize photo script frm some website and basically it work just fine but the problem is: i can only use it to upload JPG photo only if i try to upload other extensions such as : png,gif i will get the error here is my code:

```
<?
if(trim($_FILES["fileUpload"]["tmp_name"]) != "")
{
    $images = $_FILES["fileUpload"]["tmp_name"];
    $new_images = "Thumbnails_".$_FILES["fileUpload"]["name"];
    copy($_FILES["fileUpload"]["tmp_name"],"MyResize/".$_FILES["fileUpload"]["name"]);
    $width=100; //*** Fix Width & Heigh (Autu caculate) ***//
    $size=GetimageSize($images);
    $height=100;
    $images_orig = ImageCreateFromJPEG($images);
    $photoX = ImagesX($images_orig);
    $photoY = ImagesY($images_orig);
    $images_fin = ImageCreateTrueColor($width, $height);
    ImageCopyResampled($images_fin, $images_orig, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width+1, $height+1, $photoX, $photoY);
    ImageJPEG($images_fin,"MyResize/".$new_images);
    ImageDestroy($images_orig);
    ImageDestroy($images_fin);  }
```

?>

Again my Question is: how to make this script works with all extensions ?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to get the extension of the file by using `pathinfo()` and use `ImageCreateFromJPEG`, `ImageCreateFromPNG`, `ImageCreateFromGIF`, `ImageJPEG`, `ImagePNG`, and `ImageGIF` accordingly:

```
<?
if(trim($_FILES["fileUpload"]["tmp_name"]) != "")
{
    $images = $_FILES["fileUpload"]["tmp_name"];
    $new_images = "Thumbnails_".$_FILES["fileUpload"]["name"];
    copy($_FILES["fileUpload"]["tmp_name"],"MyResize/".$_FILES["fileUpload"]["name"]);
    $width=100; //*** Fix Width & Heigh (Autu caculate) ***//
    $size=GetimageSize($images);
    $height=100;
    $ext = pathinfo($images, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if($ext == "jpg")
    {
       $images_orig = ImageCreateFromJPEG($images);
    }
    elseif($ext == "png")
    {
       $images_orig = ImageCreateFromPNG($images);
    }
    elseif($ext == "gif")
    {
       $images_orig = ImageCreateFromGIF($images);
    }
    $photoX = ImagesX($images_orig);
    $photoY = ImagesY($images_orig);
    $images_fin = ImageCreateTrueColor($width, $height);
    ImageCopyResampled($images_fin, $images_orig, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width+1, $height+1, $photoX, $photoY);
    if($ext == "jpg")
    {
       ImageJPEG($images_fin,"MyResize/".$new_images);
    }
    elseif($ext == "png")
    {
       ImagePNG($images_fin,"MyResize/".$new_images);
    }
    elseif($ext == "gif")
    {
       ImageGIF($images_fin,"MyResize/".$new_images);
    }

    ImageDestroy($images_orig);
    ImageDestroy($images_fin);  }
```

Comment: Thanks for giving an idea actually i use this code and it works perfectly:`$size=GetimageSize($images);
  $height=100;
  
  switch(strtolower($size['mime']))
   {
      case 'image/png':
        $images_orig = imagecreatefrompng($images);
         break;
      case 'image/jpeg':
        $images_orig = imagecreatefromjpeg($images);
        break;
      case 'image/gif':
        $images_orig = imagecreatefromgif($images);
        break;
       default: die();
 
  }`

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP script most probably uses ImageMagick.

JPG, GIF, PNG are different image formats, with different kind of data stored.

Instructions **ImageCreateFromJPEG, ImageCreateTrueColor** and **ImageJPG** apply to JPG format only, so... start to search in ImageMagick's documentation for GIF and PNG.